# Get an app ready for ICS

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have a few apps out there which are mostly written for the api level 8. Now when I start them on an avd running ice cream sandwich they all crash either immediate or after a while. What I do not want to do now is to test all these applications and try to find errors simply because they were error-free before.

All information I have about ICS is the official difference report (http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/15/changes.html) which basically tells you what has been changed where. That is very nice, but I am not nuts comparing all those methods to all my apps. I do believe that this is insane!

So what am I asking for is a tool having a look at my source code and pointing things out which will not run on ICS. Or am I missing something? Or is there more information?

## Follow up

After all the Android Developers Team has improved their plugin for Eclipse by a mile and all errors or warnings can be viewed in Android Lint and no more **manually debugging** should be necessary anymore.

Comment: Automated tools cannot determine your intent, you're going to need to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @matthewread .. this is the age old challenge of porting your software up the chain. All's not lost, since what you'll usually find is that once you uncover a couple deltas and put some fixes in, the rest should fall into place. ICS is not that different on the whole.

One way to do it is to add some logcat catches or additional debug points for debug info. That way you can pick up more than you would normally pick up in your code as it generates exceptions. They will all be in logcat along with whatever events preceded and followed the exception. At that point you will have the problems in front of you.

BTW, the delta doc you're referring to should only be used to identify where to start looking for issues. Whatever Android services, calls etc.. that changed will be doc'd in there. Just find what you may be using and understand the changes, then turn to your software and debug...